# android ediitext ontouchlistener second tourch

Tags: android, android-edittext, ontouchlistener

I have one `EdiiText` and I wrote setOnTouchListener method and I wont to check any touch without first touch(second touch ,3th touch and etc)

```
   AgroJaninputcount.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                        iCount++;
                        System.out.println(iCount + "  iCount");
                        if(iCount >1)
                        {

                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Second Click", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        }


                        return false;
                    }
                });
```

My Toast message has seen in first time also. If anyone knows solution please help me.

thanks everyone

Answer (score 0):

Try this, Im pretty sure will solve your problem. If it does please mark my answer as correct.The problem is that  you are incrementing the value before the if.

```
 AgroJaninputcount.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

                            @Override
                            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {


                                System.out.println(iCount + "  iCount");
                                if(iCount >1)
                                {

                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Second Click", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                }

 iCount++;
                                return false;
                            }
                        });
```

Answer (score 0):

try `motionEvent.getPointerCount()`

maybe you should check, if the onTouchEvent is a ACTION_DOWN event ->

```
if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your condition

```
if(iCount >1)
```

To

```
if(iCount >2)
```